# Solution of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me to solve this differential equation.

$xy \ d x=(x^2-y^4) \ d y$

What kind of differential equation is this?

Comment: Yes, I changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we write the ode as

> $$ \frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{x}{y}-\frac{y^3}{x}.  $$

Then we use the channge of variables $x=yu$ which implies

> $$ x' = u+yu'. $$

Substituting back in the ode yields the separable ode

> $$ u+yu' = u-\frac{y^2}{u} \implies yu'= -\frac{y^2}{u}. $$

I think you can finish it.